# Filter dataframe using global variable with the same name as column name

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
```

Toy dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6))
df
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

This works fine:

```
df %>% filter(y == 5)
  x y
1 2 5
```

This also works fine:

```
z <- 5
df %>% filter(y == z)
  x y
1 2 5
```

But this fails

```
y <- 5
df %>% filter(y == y)
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Apparently, dplyr cannot make the distinction between its column `y` and the global variable `y`.
Is there a way to tell dplyr that the second y is the global variable?

Comment: you could use df %>% filter(y == get('y'))

Comment: interesting question, but it does remind me of the old "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Well, you could try not doing that." joke ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>% filter(y == .GlobalEnv$y)
```

or:

```
df %>% filter(y == .GlobalEnv[["y"]])
```

or:

both of which work in this context, but won't if all this is going on inside a function. But `get` will:

```
df %>% filter(y == get("y"))
f = function(df, y){df %>% filter(y==get("y"))}
```

So use `get`.

Or just use `df[df$y==y,]` **instead of** `dplyr`.

Answer (score 8):

The global environment can be accessed via the `.GlobalEnv` object:

```
> filter(df, y==.GlobalEnv$y)
  x y
1 2 5
```

Interestingly, using the accessor function `globalenv()` as a substitute for `.GlobalEnv` doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: `globalenv()` fails because any function call with a `$y` on it will fail, because `dplyr` seems to do some bad things to expressions like `foo()$y` if there's a `y` in your data frame. Horrible.

Comment: `globalenv()[["y"]]` on the other hand does work. It's always the `$` that gives problems.

Comment: Its the non-standard evaluation of `dplyr` that gives problems. Recall that without `dplyr` the code is simply `df[df$y==y,]`.

Comment: @Spacedman NSE doesn't have anything to do with it, save indirectly. `subset(df, y==globalenv()$y)` works, for example. This is just a good old-fashioned bug in dplyr.